# nightly build Script for SubVersion

Tags: svn, nightly-build

I have prepared a solution with multiple projects with Netbeans IDE versioned under Linux with Subversion.

I would like to prepare a script that automatize nightly build creation:
- checkout latest version from the SVN
- compile multiple projects
- choose a subset of files (libraries, headers, etc...)
- tar.gz them
- commit the tar.gz to the SVN

Some suggestions?
Thanks in advance
Ciao
Andrea

Comment: Are you using a build tool like ant or maven?  If not, that is the place to start

Comment: As a side note, checking in lots of binary files every night (tar.gz) might eventually slow down your SVN repository, it is usually better to keep the built product outside SVN.

Answer (score 1):

The google phrase is continous integration.

For Java you can start with checking out [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/). You can configure it to run both nightly builds and continous integration (on every checking in SVN). The actual build script would be written in [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or similar.

Comment: I would suggest Hudson as continuous integration server, and Maven or Gradle for build script.